# Banner component not changing images on mobile devices

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Just wanted to check if there is a bug ticket for banner component not changing its' image on smaller screens ie different devices, especially Android devices? The image always stays the same, no matter what other images you have defined in impex file. This is replicable on https://spartacus.c39j2-walkersde1-d4-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/ as well.

Answer (score 1):

currently we have one ticket in github for this problem. Please follow it there: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-commerce-spartacus-storefront/issues/5395